# Why doesn't (Vim plugin) NetRW browse function open directories and files?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, netrw

I'm using MacVim 7.3 snapshot 66 (latest as of Dec 2012) with NetRW v147b. When I run `mvim .` from the command line, it runs NetRW, but the browse behavior is very strange.

My NetRW window looks like this (notice the weird full paths, instead of relative paths):

```
| Users/me/chef/cookbooks/windows/recipes/
| Users/me/chef/cookbooks/windows/resources/
| Users/me/chef/cookbooks/windows/CHANGELOG.md
| Users/me/chef/cookbooks/windows/CONTRIBUTING
| Users/me/chef/cookbooks/windows/LICENSE
|
```

When I hit `ENTER` on a line it does nothing for directories and for files, it opens a new, blank Vim buffer as [New DIRECTORY].

NetRW used to work as expected, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it do the same when you do `:Explore`?

Comment: Yes, :Explore produces the exact same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, through the magic of `git bisect` I discovered the exact NetRW option with causes this issue:

```
" default to tree-style listing, like NERDTree
let g:netrw_liststyle=3
```

Comment: So, you're just using a different liststyle now?